# add_media_page function not creating submenu

Tags: plugins, menus, actions

I have the following plugin that I'm just testing at the moment.

```
/*
Plugin Name: Menu Test
Plugin URI: http://codex.wordpress.org/Adding_Administration_Menus
Description: Menu Test
Author: Codex authors
Author URI: http://example.com
*/


include('./customFields.php');

// Hook for adding admin menus
add_action('admin_menu', array('customFields', 'buildOptions'));

// action function for above hook
```

And the class that goes with it in customFields.php

```
class customFields {

    private function createMenu () {
        add_media_page('Custom Media Options', 'Add Fields to Media',     'manage_options', 'custom_media_options', $this::createMenuOptionsPage());

    }

    private function createMenuOptionsPage () {
        echo 'test';

    }

    public function buildOptions () {
        $this::createMenu();
    }

}
```

I can't see anything wrong with my syntax, but the submenu under media never appears.  Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you would use a class method within add_action function, then within the array parameter, you have to pass an instance of that class as the first value and then you the method name as the second value of the array. In your code, you did not pass any instance actually. And that's why it did not work.

Try this:

```
class customFields {

    private function createMenu () {
        add_media_page('Custom Media Options', 'Add Fields to Media',     'manage_options', 'custom_media_options', $this->createMenuOptionsPage());

    }

    private function createMenuOptionsPage () {
        echo 'test';

    }

    public function buildOptions () {
        $this->createMenu();
    }

}  

$customFields = new customFields();
add_action('admin_menu', array($customFields, 'buildOptions'));
```

Comment: Please explain _why_ this answer is helpful.

Comment: In an [edit] please, not a comment. Make your answer easily understandable.